# Using definition, prove that $B$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

$$B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x,y||_{2} \lt 1, ||(x,y)-(0,-1)||_{\infty} \gt 1 \}$$

From my calculations we can rewrite $B$ as $B=A \cap C$ where $$A=K((0,0),1)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^2:d(x,y) \lt 1 \}$$

$$C=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:y \gt 0 \}$$

$A$ is open ball around $0$. To prove something is open by definition, my professor means $\forall x \in B$ there exists $r \gt 0$ such that $K(x,r) \subseteq B$.

Now, part of my solution. Let $(x_0,y_0) \in B$. From my sketch we have to take $$r:=\min{ \{ 1-d(x_0,y_0), y_0 \}}$$ Now let $(x,y) \in K((x_0,y_0),r)$. I have to prove that $(x,y) \in B$. Now I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by open you mean open wrt the Euclidean distance and $d$ is your notation for distance from the origin, while $K$ is an open ball for this distance. It could help to draw a picture: the set is just the upper half of the open unit disk in $ {\mathbf R}^2 $.

So given a point $(x_0,y_0) \in B $, taking $ r $ as $ \min \{ y_0,  1-\sqrt{ x_0^2+y_0^2} \} $ as you have done, does the job. $ r \le y_0 $ ensures the ball $ K((x_0,y_0),r) $ is contained in $C$ while the other inequality that it is contained in $A$.